# Move cursor to the start of line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How to move cursor to the start of a line in Notepad++?

I found no explanation in a Google search (all I found deals with regex).

I'm looking for a key combo just to move the cursor in row to the start (or end) of the current row.

Comment: did you google for "go to start of line shortcut"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> on your keyboard are for. It is also not limited to notepad++ but will work with (probably nearly) all text editors.

Comment: Even the official documentation for the editor does not have a short cut linked to `goto to beginning of line` and `goto end of line` shortcut. I think your answer is right

Comment: it works in all standard textboxes except vim and emacs

Comment: Nice I didn't know these options, though, I must say, it seems that `home` works bidirectionally in my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on @prasanna's answer.. you can also use **ctrl** and **left or right** on the keyboard, to jump from word to word